# payment block rewrite not working

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I want to rewrite `Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php` with another file inside my module.

In my module's config file, I have:

```
<global>
  <blocks>
     <payment_form>
         <rewrite>
            <container>Mynamespace_Module_Block_Form_Container</container>
         </rewrite>
     </payment_form>
  </blocks>
</global>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<global>
 <blocks>
   <payment>
     <rewrite>
        <form_container>Mynamespace_Module_Block_Form_Container</form_container>
   </rewrite>
  </payment>
 </blocks>
</global>
```

I have then, in my Module, `Mynamespace/Module/Block/Form/Container.php`

```
<?php

class Mynamespace_Module_Block_Form_Container extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  protected function _prepareLayout()
  {
    echo "hello world";
  }
}
```

none of the above solutions are working. it's still picking up the old block inside `Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php`

Could it be because my module lives in local code pool??

Answer (score 0):

Change this:
`<container_form>Mynamespace_Module_Block_Form_Container</container_form>`

to this:
`<form_container>Mynamespace_Module_Block_Form_Container</form_container>`

Comment: well, turns out it was a typo. it's `form_container` in my code. where else should i look into?? I've disabled the compilation and caching ( all sorts ). still, it picks up the old container block.

Comment: Another thing is: `Mynamespace_Module_Block_Form_Container` should extend `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container`, not `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. Do you have any other extensions that rewrite that block? You can check conflicts using the `Firegento_Debug`module